# How can I select an annotation in Okular by clicking on the particular annotation on the corresponding page of a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, annotations, okular

How can I select an Okular annotation by clicking on the particular annotation on the corresponding page of the pdf file?

I can do this by clicking on the annotations toolbar but that does not let me to recognize the annotation I select out of the many annotations a page might contain.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To Select, you must be in "Browse" mode. From main menu: Tools/Browse.

Don't know why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).